# Using mysql for a mini game

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to mysql and wanted to consult about using mysql for my mini game. The idea is that from a game i get two variables - one is email, and another is score.

I'm thinking of creating a table with two columns and setting email as the primary.

The question is how do I make php script replace score value for a player which tries for the second time?

For example user@user.com scores 100 in the first try, script adds that as INSERT INTO table VALUES ($email,$score); then user tries another time, same script tries to add but gets duplicate error. Any help on script logic would be great! cheers

Comment: wasn't me, can't do that yet :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (email, score)
VALUES  ($email, $score)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
SET     score = $score
```

This requires `email` to be the `PRIMARY KEY` of `mytable`.

Comment: syntax would be something like this?

$query = "INSERT INTO irasai VALUES (email,score) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET score = $score";
?

Comment: @user: see my post for the correct syntax. Replace `$email` and `$score` with actual values, `mytable`, `email` and `score` with actual table and field names.

Comment: thanks, working. Any tips on updating only if the new score is higher? :)

Comment: @user: `SET score = LEAST(score, $score)`

Comment: should have been GREATEST instead of least, but still, thanks. Do I have to run another query to echo that you gained xx more points than you had?

Comment: @user: please post each question as a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without more details. If there is some sort of session or pre-registering of the player, you could insert a "default score" of zero, for instance, and then always update instead of insert. If not, Queassnoi's solution is probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) rather than INSERT

```
UPDATE table SET score = $newScore where email=$email
```

You are trying to add a new record with the same primary key, hence the error message